# How to retrieve number of records from mysql database in a group?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with multiple records in it for full name and surname.

```
---------------------------
id | name       | lastname
---------------------------
 1 | A smith    | smith
 2 | B smith    | smith
 3 | c smith    | smith
 4 | A josh     | josh
 5 | B josh     | josh
 6 | C josh     | josh
 7 | D josh     | josh
 8 | A white    | white
 9 | D white    | white
 10| z white    | white
```

And so so....more than 100k records. Now what i want to do is to retrieve latest 7 records for each surname up to 9 surnames. I have 500 surnames but i just want latest 9 surnames..  In my application "latest" means "largest value of `id` column."

This is the command that i tried to make but when i execute it. i am not getting any response from server. this is happening because of database size and my command is taking a lot of time. its just keep me waiting:

```
SELECT * FROM `queue` s WHERE ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `queue` f WHERE f.lastname = s.lastname AND f.id >= s.id LIMIT 0 , 7) <=7
```

Can someone suggest me better way of retrieving my goal.

Comment: *latest* implies that you have a time/date column.

Comment: @DanFromGermany no, latest means id that i provide to each new record in ascending order.

Comment: auto increment/primary key id is not necessarily the most recent row

Comment: @DanFromGermany Yep! All i need to retrieve 7 records for each surname up to 9 surname

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's build this up from the basics.

Your first step is to create a subquery to get the latest nine surnames (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aee62e/19/0).  By that I mean the surnames with the highest `id` values.

```
                        SELECT lastname, MAX(id) namerank
                          FROM t
                         GROUP BY lastname
                         ORDER BY MAX(id) DESC
                         LIMIT 9
```

And, in MySQL, that was the easy part.  Now you need to retrieve the seven highest ranked (largest `id`) rows for each selected surname.  As a start, you could do this to get *all* records for the selected surnames, in descending order by id.  (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aee62e/18/0).

```
              SELECT t.*, namerank
                FROM t
                JOIN (          
                        SELECT lastname, MAX(id) namerank
                          FROM t
                         GROUP BY lastname
                         ORDER BY MAX(id) DESC
                         LIMIT 9
                      ) h ON t.lastname = h.lastname
                ORDER BY t.lastname, t.id DESC
```

This is correct, but contains too many rows.  Next we need to get the ranking for each `lastname`'s rows.  A lower ranking means a higher `id` value.  This is the nasty hack in MySQL.  (Nasty because it mixes procedural operations on local variables with the inherently declarative nature of SQL.)  (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aee62e/17/0)

```
     SELECT IF(detail.lastname = @prev_lastname, @rank := @rank+1, @rank :=1)  rank, 
            namerank,
            @prev_lastname := detail.lastname lastname,
            id,
            name
       FROM (
              SELECT t.*, namerank
                FROM t
                JOIN (          
                        SELECT lastname, MAX(id) namerank
                          FROM t
                         GROUP BY lastname
                         ORDER BY MAX(id) DESC
                         LIMIT 9
                      ) h ON t.lastname = h.lastname
                ORDER BY t.lastname, t.id DESC
            ) detail
       JOIN (SELECT @rank := 0, @prev_lastname := '') initializer
```

Finally we need to wrap that whole mess in an outer query to pick off the seven highest ranked rows for each `lastname` value. (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aee62e/16/0)

```
SELECT *
  FROM (

         SELECT IF(detail.lastname = @prev_lastname, @rank := @rank+1, @rank :=1)  rank, 
                namerank,
                @prev_lastname := detail.lastname lastname,
                id,
                name
           FROM (
                  SELECT t.*, namerank
                    FROM t
                    JOIN (          
                            SELECT lastname, MAX(id) namerank
                              FROM t
                             GROUP BY lastname
                             ORDER BY MAX(id) DESC
                             LIMIT 9
                          ) h ON t.lastname = h.lastname
                    ORDER BY t.lastname, t.id DESC
                ) detail
           JOIN (SELECT @rank := 0, @prev_lastname := '') initializer
         ) ranked
 WHERE rank <= 7
ORDER BY namerank DESC, rank
```

I believe the technical term for the complexity of your requirement and this solution is "hairball." It definitely puts the *structured* in *Structured Query Language*.

Comment: Awesome. Only one comment - it should be seven, not "nine highest ranked rows". Your query does that but the words are wrong.

Comment: Awesome dude! Your code is lengthy but does exactly what i want. Hats off to you :)

Comment: Thanks @Nick . Fixed. It was confusing, because I had to use two, in both places, in the fiddle. The test data set wasn't big enough for seven or nine of anything.